# How to build a function object like the built-ins such as Interpolation?

Tags: function-construction, output-formatting

There are many *built-in* functions that return a **function object**, such as `Interpolation[]`, `BSplineFunction[]` ,`LinearSolveFunction[]` and so on.

[image]

---

Now given that I want to build a function called `CAGDBSplineFunction[]` like the *built-in* `BSplineFunction[]` with the help of *Cox-DeBoor* algorithm.

**First trial**, please see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96781/how-to-build-a-function-object-like-the-built-ins-such-as-interpolation/96958#96958)

To achieve the **dynamic** effect and check the **validity of the option** like the *built-in* `BSplineFunction`

[image]

I refactored it as below:

```
CAGDBSplineFunction::invknots = 
  "Value of option SplineKnots \[Rule] `1` should be a non-decreasing \
   real sequence of length `2`, or a symbol Automatic.";

Options[CAGDBSplineFunction] = 
  {SplineDegree -> Automatic, SplineKnots -> Automatic};

CAGDBSplineFunction /: 
 MakeBoxes[CAGDBSplineFunction[pts_, opts : OptionsPattern[]], _] := 
 Module[{n, sk, sd, range},
  n = Length@pts - 1;
  sk = OptionValue[SplineKnots];
  sd = OptionValue[SplineDegree];
  (*check the validity of the option SplineKnots*)
  If[sk =!= Automatic,
   If[n + 1 + sd != Length[sk] - 1, 
    Message[CAGDBSplineFunction::invknots, sk, n + 2 + sd];
    Return[$Failed]];
    range = Through[{First, Last}@sk],
   range = {0, 1}
  ]
 ]
 InterpretationBox[
   RowBox[{"CAGDBSplineFunction", "[", "{", #1, ",", #2, "}", ",", 
   "\"<>\"", "]"}], CAGDBSplineFunction[pts, opts]] & @@ range
]
```

**TEST**

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {3, 0}, {4, -2}, {5, 1}};
f = CAGDBSplineFunction[pts]
```

[image]

However, it seems that the option value **cannot** be achieved in a `MakeBoxes` construct.

J.M. gives me the following suggestion:

> Don't try to do both display and processing at once. Set a definition for evaluating `CAGDBSplineFunction[]`, and then set a definition for displaying, via `MakeBoxes`

According to the J.M.'s hint, I add the defintion to `CAGDBSplineFunction[]`

```
CAGDBSplineFunction /: 
 MakeBoxes[CAGDBSplineFunction[pts_, opts : OptionsPattern[]], _] := 
  InterpretationBox[
    RowBox[{"CAGDBSplineFunction", "[", "{", #1, ",", #2, "}", ",", 
  "\"<>\"", "]"}], CAGDBSplineFunction[pts, opts]] & @@ 
    CAGDBSplineFunction[pts, opts]

CAGDBSplineFunction[pts_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[
  {n, sk, sd, range},
  n = Length@pts - 1;
  sk = OptionValue[SplineKnots];
  sd = OptionValue[SplineDegree] /. Automatic -> 3;
  (*check the validity of the option SplineKnots*)
  If[sk =!= Automatic,
   If[n + 1 + sd != Length[sk] - 1, 
    Message[CAGDBSplineFunction::invknots, sk, n + 2 + sd];
    Return[$Failed]];
    range = Through[{First, Last}@sk],
   range = {0, 1}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Something like `constructor[pts_, deg_] := excecutor[someStructure[pts, deg]];
excecutor[someStructure[pts_, deg_]][t_] := 
  doSomething[someStructure[pts, deg, t]];
myfun = constructor[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, 1];
myfun[t]` ?

Comment: With respect to version 10-style output formatting of such functions, see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77658).

Comment: You coud try an approach similar to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10385).

Comment: That was supposed to be the "simple demo". Did you look at how the function's output format was implemented, and how the evaluation is done?

Comment: (1) Construction: Define `makemyfn[stuff_]` to return object `myfn[data]`. (2) Format `myfn` with with `MakeBoxes` as in the linked questions in the comments. (3) Computation: Define sub-value `myfn[datastructure_][input_] := (* computation *)` for the computation, using whatever patterns for `datastructure` that are appropriate. -- Which is what belisarius said, but seems to have been ignored?

Comment: You could separate the function that *creates* the function object from the function object itself.  `Interpolation` is distinct from `InterpolatingFunction`.  The insides of the latter are of no concern to users, thus there's no need to do syntax checking on them.

Comment: @Szabolcs, thanks a lot for your suggestion, could you give me a **specific** example? I need to learn how the built-in construct the **function object**. In addition, the built-in `BSplineFunction` indeed do the syntax checking. For instance,`f = BSplineFunction[{{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}}, SplineKnots -> {1, 2, 3}]` throws the error info `BSplineFunction::invknots`

Comment: In that case, the definition would look like `BSplineFunction[pts_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{(* stuff *)}, (* stuff *) If[testQ[OptionValue[SplineKnots]], (* throw messages *)]; (* more stuff *) BSplineFunction[(* internal data *)]]`. The idea is to have two definitions for `BSplineFunction[]`: one where it processes data into a definite internal format, and one where its arguments are already in the internal format. The formatting rules are then applied to the latter one.

Answer (score 4):

It is not easy to show the domain dynamicly when the domain was been given by the option, for instance, in your function `CAGDBSplineFunction`,the option `SplineKnots -> Automatic`.

In the [`SphericalLinearInterpolation[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10384/fast-spherical-linear-interpolation-of-list-of-quaternions/10385#10385), the `range` was given by the *arguments*, rather than the *option*. So it is easy to implement the **dynamic domain** by pure function.

```
MakeBoxes[SphericalInterpolatingFunction[range_, rest__], _] ^:= 
 InterpretationBox[
  RowBox[
   {"SphericalInterpolatingFunction", "[", "{", #1, ",",
     #2, "}", ",", "\"<>\"", "]"}], 
SphericalInterpolatingFunction[range, rest]] & @@ Map[ToBoxes, range]
```

---

To achieve the goal, you should reference the package `Splines` in your *Mathematica* install directory

> XXX\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\9.0\AddOns\Packages\Splines

For instance, the following code can help you(Notice the defintion of the `SubValues` of `SplineFunction[type, {min, max}, pts,internal]`)

```
Format[SplineFunction[t_,r_, b__]] :=
Row[{"SplineFunction[",t,", ", r,", ","<>","]"}]

SplineFunction[type_, {min_, max_}, pts_,internal_][in_?(NumberQ[N[#]]&)] :=
Module[{out},
    If[in < min || in > max,
        Message[SplineFunction::dmval, in];
        out = $Failed,
  (* else *)
   out = evalspline[
     Which[in == max, Min[max, in],
        in == min, Max[min, in],
        True, in], type, pts, internal]
  ];
  out/;out =!= $Failed
]
```

---

```
Format[CAGDBSplineFunction1[pts_, opts : OptionsPattern[]]] :=
 Module[{n, sk, range},
  sk = SplineKnots /. {opts} /. Options[CAGDBSplineFunction];
  If[sk === Automatic, 
    range = {0, 1}, 
    range = Through[{First, Last}@sk]
  ];
 Row[
   {"CAGDBSplineFunction1", "[", "{", sk, , ",", range, "}", ",", 
   "<>", "]"}]    
 ]

pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {3, 0}, {4, -2}, {5, 1}};
CAGDBSplineFunction[pts, SplineKnots -> Range[0, 9]]
```

[image]

In addition, you should not use the `OptionValue`, rather than `SplineKnots /. {opts} /. Options[CAGDBSplineFunction]`

[image]