# How to Return $Failed symbol in a MakeBoxes context?

Tags: programming, function-construction, formatting

Three months ago, I asked a [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96781/how-to-build-a-function-object-like-the-built-ins-such-as-interpolation) about **How to build a function object like the built-ins?**

Today, I used a [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77658/how-to-create-a-dynamic-expanding-displayforms-styled-like-the-ones-in-v10/79891#79891) proposed by István Zachar

```
Options[CAGDBSplineFunction] = {SplineDegree -> 3, SplineKnots -> Automatic};

CAGDBSplineFunction::invdeg = 
 "Value of option SplineDegree \[Rule] `1` should be a machine integer 
  or a symbol Automatic.";

CAGDBSplineFunction::invknots = 
 "Value of option SplineKnots \[Rule] `1` should be a valid knots sequence
  or a symbol Automatic.";
```

---

```
CAGDBSplineFunction /:
 MakeBoxes[obj_CAGDBSplineFunction, 
  form : (StandardForm | TraditionalForm)] :=
Module[{o = List @@ obj, n, crtlpts, shown, hidden, opts, options,
  icon = Graphics[{Blue, Circle[]}, ImageSize -> 35], sd, sk},
  ctrlpts = First@o;
  n = Length@crtlpts - 1;
  opts = Rest[o];
  options = Options[CAGDBSplineFunction];
  sd = SplineDegree /. opts /. options;
  sk = SplineKnots /. opts /. options;
  (*check the validness of SplineDegree*)
  If[! IntegerQ[sd],
   Message[CAGDBSplineFunction::invdeg, sd];
   Return[$Failed]
  ];

  (*check the validness of SplineKnots*)
  If[sk === Automatic, 
   sk = 
    Join[
     ConstantArray[0.0, sd + 1],
     Range[n - sd]/(n - sd + 1), ConstantArray[1.0, sd + 1]],
   If[n + 1 + sd != Length[sk] - 1 || ! OrderedQ[sk], 
    Message[CAGDBSplineFunction::invknots, sk, n + 2 + sd];
    Return[$Failed]
   ]
  ];
 shown =
   {{BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Argument count: ", 1}, form], SpanFromLeft},
    {BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Output dimention: ", 2}, form]}};
 hidden =
   {{BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Degree: ", sd}, form]},
    {BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Knots: ", sk}, form]}, 
    {BoxForm`MakeSummaryItem[{"Control points: ", ctrlpts}, form]}};
 BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[
  CAGDBSplineFunction, o, icon, shown, hidden, form, 
  "Interpretable" -> False]
 ]
```

Test

```
pts = {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}};
CAGDBSplineFunction[pts, SplineDegree -> 4]
```

[image]

However, when the option value of `SplineDegree` is invaid, *Mathematcia* will throw the following error:

```
CAGDBSplineFunction[pts, SplineDegree -> 2.3]
```

[image]

> An unknown box name (Return) was sent as the BoxForm for the expression. Check the format rules for the expression.

Comment: I don't know what is the question but you may be interested in `Return[$Failed, Module]` instead of just `Return[$Failed]`.

Comment: `MakeBoxes` is `HoldAllComplete`, and boxes are for display only. Therefore it is incumbent on you to ensure you pass fully-formed, correct expressions to `MakeBoxes`, so that within the generated boxes there is no *Mathematica* code.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks  a lot:) It works well.

Comment: @ShutaoTANG but this check, as pointed by Oleksandr R., should be included in the "kernel" code in the first place.

Comment: @Kuba Sorry, what does the "included in the "kernel" code" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, extending comments. Quick fix is to use `Return[$Failed, Module]` here but it's not the right approach.

This `SplineDegree` should not reach `MakeBoxes` at all. Here's what should be done.

Imo, the user should not use `CAGDBSplineFunction` manually to create it, like in case of `InterpolatingFunction` it is created by something else, here `Interpolation`.

So in addition to your definitions you should have something like (minimal example):

```
Options[CAGDBSpline] = Options[CAGDBSplineFunction];

CAGDBSpline[pts_, patt : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{
   sd = OptionValue@SplineDegree
   },
   If[ IntegerQ @ sd,
     CAGDBSplineFunction[pts, patt],
     Message[CAGDBSplineFunction::invdeg, sd]; $Failed
   ]
]
```

And `CAGDBSpline` is what the user should use. Now:

```
CAGDBSpline[pts, SplineDegree -> 4.5]

CAGDBSpline[pts, SplineDegree -> 1]
```

> CAGDBSplineFunction::invdeg: Value of option SplineDegree -> 4.5` should be a machine integer or a symbol Automatic.
>
> [image]

Comment: Namely, using another function `CAGDBSpline`. However, for the built-in `BSplineFunction[]`, `pts = {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}}; BSplineFunction[pts, SplineDegree -> 3.2]` throws the error information `BSplineFunction::invdeg`. Did you know how to achieve that like `BSplineFunction[]` ? THX very much.

Comment: @ShutaoTANG They are using something like `MakeBoxes[bsp_ BSplineFunction,fmt_]/;UseIcons&&ValidQ[Unevaluated[bsp]]:=makeSplineBoxes[bsp,fmt];` and it is `makeSplineBoxes` which creates the `SummaryBox` if `ValidQ` returns `True`.